# Can I use the Navigation Controller on Document Provider extensions to simulate folder navigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm implementing a Document Provider for my application where I have to simulate folders navigation.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html) says:

> In either case, the host app presents a document picker view
>   controller. The system then imbeds your Document Picker View
>   Controller extension inside the app’s view controller. The app’s view
>   controller provides a navigation bar with the document provider’s
>   name, a location switcher, and a Done button. Your extension must
>   provide the rest of the user interface.

And:

> The `UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController` object acts as the root
>   view controller for your user interface; therefore, it is often
>   convenient to make it a container controller. You can then create a
>   separate child view controllers for each mode, and your extension
>   simply presents the appropriate child view controller in your
>   `prepareForPresentationInMode:` method.

Is there a way to use the main navigation controller to be able to push custom view controllers and simulate the same behaviour of the iCloud Document Provider extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, If you put your navigation controller you will see both navigation bars - your and the system. The system navigation bar is private and you don't have access to it. For now you can't make a document provider extension like iCloud.